# the interface is not updated with the latest data saved to core data swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface

these days I start to learn ios applications development using SWIFT language

so I started to build my own app which contain forms that collect information from users and save\retrieve it to\from core data

my home page hide/show its buttons depending on data retrieved from the core data and do simple check on it so the data have to be up to date to avoid mistakes

but when I add user to the Core data and return to the home page it show the buttons as nothing has been added but if leave the home page to other page and then back to home page then the last user added appears

it seems like  the context did not finish the data saving before the home appears
How I can fix that and ensure that the context object finish saving then show the home page
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that waiting for context to save before performing segue might be **not** the best solution - depending on task it can take a long time. If use this approach you should show some progress indicator to user or smth. 
Otherwise it will look like your app UI is freezing and that is a bad UX.

Anyway answering your question you have 3 basic solutions :

- use competition closure
- use delegation
- use notifications

I assume you use some sort of custom class to load the CoreData Stack and you probably have function for saving context. Than it might look like this :

```
    private func saveContext(completition : (()->() )?) {
    if let moc = self.context {
        var error : NSError? = nil

        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error){
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
            abort()
        }

        //Call delegate method
        delegate?.MiniCoreDataStackDidSaveContext()

        //Send notification message
        defaultCenter.postNotificationName("MyContextDidSaveNotification", object: self)

        //Perform completition closure
        if let closure = completition {
            closure()
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it like this :

```
MyCoreDataStack.saveContext(){
  performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_ID,nil)
}
```

or

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("MyContextDidSaveNotification",
            object: MyCoreDataStack.saveContext,
            queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            usingBlock: { _ in performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_ID, sender: nil) }
        )
```

In case you don't have any Stack - I've written this small singleton class as an **example** it lacks of proper error handling etc. 
In a private function *saveContext* it combines all three approaches (*it's only for example*, I would not advice to use delegation with singleton pattern)

```
import CoreData


protocol MiniCoreDataStackDelegate : class {
   func MiniCoreDataStackDidSaveContext()
}

@objc(MiniCoreDataStack)
class MiniCoreDataStack {

struct Constants {
    static let persistentStoreName          = "Store"
    static let contextSaveNotification      = "MiniCoreDataStackDidSaveContextNotification"
}

private var managedObjectModel : NSManagedObjectModel
private var persistentStoreCoordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = nil
private var store : NSPersistentStore?
private let defaultCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

var defaultContext : NSManagedObjectContext!

var stackIsLoaded : Bool = false

weak var delegate : MiniCoreDataStackDelegate?

class var defaultModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
    return NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)!
}

class var sharedInstance: MiniCoreDataStack  {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = MiniCoreDataStack()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}


class func storesDirectory() -> NSURL {
    let applicationDocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last as! NSURL
    return applicationDocumentsDirectory
}

private func storeURLForName(name:String) -> NSURL {
    return MiniCoreDataStack.storesDirectory().URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).sqlite")
}

func localStoreOptions() -> NSDictionary {
    return [
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true,
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true
    ]
}

init( model : NSManagedObjectModel = MiniCoreDataStack.defaultModel){
    managedObjectModel = model
}


func openStore(completion:(()->Void)?) {
    println("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)):  \(__FUNCTION__)")

    var error: NSError? = nil
    let tempPersistenStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)


    if let newStore = tempPersistenStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: self.storeURLForName(Constants.persistentStoreName), options: self.localStoreOptions() as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error){
        self.persistentStoreCoordinator = tempPersistenStoreCoordinator


        defaultContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        defaultContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        defaultContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator


        self.stackIsLoaded = true
        println("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)):  Store loaded")

        if let completionClosure = completion {
            completionClosure()
        }

    } else {
        println("\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)): !!! Could not add persistent store !!!")
        println(error?.localizedDescription)
    }

}

private func saveContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext? = MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.defaultContext!, completition : (()->() )?) {
    if !self.stackIsLoaded {
        return
    }

    if let moc = context {
        var error : NSError? = nil

        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error){
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
            abort()
        }

        //Call delegate method
        delegate?.MiniCoreDataStackDidSaveContext()

        //Send notification message
        defaultCenter.postNotificationName(Constants.contextSaveNotification, object: self)

        //Perform completition closure
        if let closure = completition {
            closure()
        }
    }
}

func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext? = MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.defaultContext!,completition : (()->() )? ) {
    //Perform save on main thread

    if (NSThread.isMainThread()) {
        saveContext(context: context,completition: completition)
    }else {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
            self.saveContext(context: context, completition : completition)
        }
    }
}


func fetchResultsControllerForEntity(entity : NSEntityDescription, predicate :NSPredicate? = nil, sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, sectionNameKeyPath:String? = nil, cacheName: String? = nil,inManagedContext context : NSManagedObjectContext? = nil ) ->NSFetchedResultsController {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 25

    var aContext = context ?? self.defaultContext!

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: aContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: cacheName)

    var error: NSError?
    if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error){
        println("Could not fetch : \(error)")
    }

    return fetchedResultsController
}

func executeFetchRequest(request : NSFetchRequest, context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) -> [NSManagedObject] {
    var fetchedObjects = [NSManagedObject]()

    let managedContext = context ?? defaultContext

    managedContext?.performBlockAndWait{
        var error: NSError?
        if let result = managedContext?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) {
            if let managedObjects = result as? [NSManagedObject] {
                fetchedObjects = managedObjects
            }
        }
        if let err = error{
            println(err)
        }
    }

    return fetchedObjects
}

func insertEntityWithClassName(className :String, andAttributes attributesDictionary : NSDictionary? = nil, andContext context : NSManagedObjectContext = MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.defaultContext ) -> NSManagedObject {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(className, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
    if let attributes = attributesDictionary {
        attributes.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock({
            (dictKey : AnyObject!, dictObj : AnyObject!, stopBool) -> Void in
            entity.setValue(dictObj, forKey: dictKey as! String)
        })
    }
    return entity
}

func deleteEntity(entity: NSManagedObject){
    self.defaultContext!.deleteObject(entity)
}

}
```

Using Stack :

```
    //Open store
    MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.openStore()
    //Insert Entity 
    let newEntity =   MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.insertEntityWithClassName(YourEntityName)
    //Saving
    MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.save(){
        // completition closure
    }
    //Perform fetch request
    MiniCoreDataStack.sharedInstance.executeFetchRequest(YourFetchRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer 
I did not know where to look to know what I have to do
now I will try what you said and see what I can get